# Is it possible to search by genre on Soundcloud API?

Tags: php, soundcloud

Is it possible to search Soundcloud by music genre/tags when you use its API? How can I can go about doing it if it is possible?

Comment: It might help to show what you've tried and what specifically goes wrong. Also see [GET
​/tracks](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/explorer/open-api#/search/get_tracks): "Performs a track search based on a query", which can include a "comma separated list of genres [and] tags".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is possible.

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/tracks#filtering

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

You will find your Genre using sound cloud api, http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?genres=rock&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID.

I hope this will help you.